# Django Integer and Decimal field multiplication

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how to multiply a decimal field value by an integer field value.

Here is my model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, editable=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product')
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    total_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    picked = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm trying to multiple the "sale_price" column by the "qty" column but get the following error:

```
Invalid literal for Decimal: u'180.00180.00'
```

Using this code:

```
def orderItemPs(sender, instance=False, **kwargs):
    #figure out the total
    instance.total = decimal.Decimal(int(instance.qty) * instance.sale_price)
    instance.total_tax = decimal.Decimal(int(instance.qty) * instance.tax)
    #disconnect
    post_save.disconnect(orderItemPs, sender=OrderItem)
    instance.save()
    #reconnect
    post_save.connect(orderItemPs, sender=OrderItem)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers,
Sn0rcha!

**UPDATE:** Further information.

I've changed the code that was triggering off the post_save function to the following.

```
order_item = OrderItem(order=form, product=Product.objects.get(pk=products[i]), qty=int(qtys[i]), original_price=decimal.Decimal(original_prices[i]), tax=decimal.Decimal(taxs[i]), user=request.user, sale_price=decimal.Decimal(sale_prices[i]))
```

to make sure I'm casting the form values correctly prior to saving the model. I changed the 2 lines in the post save function to:

```
instance.total = decimal.Decimal(instance.qty * instance.sale_price)
instance.total_tax = decimal.Decimal(instance.qty * instance.tax)
```

However now I get the error:

```
quantize result has too many digits for current context
```

I'm using POSTGres not that it's an error on it's end.

Comment: shouldn't you cast total to a float instead of int?

Comment: @ArgsKwargs: No. Quantity is countable.

Comment: Does your schema match your model?

Comment: You are making progress here, but we can't debug this for you without more information. The context error likely means that one of your decimals has been set to have digits and decimal places that don't contain the value you're passing to it. Your model spec above is pretty strict (i.e., total_tax allows 2 digits and 2 decimal places, so 1.00 is too big). Check each value you're casting. Do any not conform with the spec, either in terms of decimal places or total digits?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `int(instance.qty)` is `2`, and `instance.sale_price` is `'180.00'`-- a string, not a numeric value, which, when multiplied by two, just duplicates the string:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(2 * '180.00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3844, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '180.00180.00'
```

How is `sale_price` being set? I would hope that Django casts it as a Decimal, but is it possible it's being stored as a string somehow?

Comment: I don't understand how python is having an issue with this, driving me nuts =/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I apologize if the one way is obvious to all but me, but if there's really only one way that could happen, do tell.